# sonar github plugin for scala [sonarqube] [github]

Tags: scala, github, sonarqube

Using sonar github plugin, I successfully did for several java base based projects
jenkins -> sonar scan -> github pull request

I need to do the same thing for scala based project (regular scala sonar run is good as well).

However, this plugin (sonar-github) seems to dropping all scala scan results.
Anyone with luck for it? Or it is impossible to do? or I need another plugin?
Thanks

Chris L

Comment: The GitHub plugin reports new issues only, that is issues that are not yet known on SonarQube. Are you saying that new issues are not reported? (They should be.) If that's the case, do you have a minimal reproducible example Scala project?

Answer (score 1):

There's no official code analyzer for Scala. That's the reason why no issues are detected on Scala code.

Note that it does not relate to the GitHub plugin, which aims to decorate pull requests with the issues raised by code analyzers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. We understood that scala is not an officially supported language for sonar. However, with third party plugin that we used, https://github.com/ncredinburgh/sonar-scalastyle, we can run the sonar scan for scala scan result with no issues. So is there some way for this plugin to make use of the scala scan result (or invoke it)